# Positive values from Datediff without using ABS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CASE 1 = 1
THEN ISNULL(Convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(day, DATE1, DATE2)),'')
```

I need to have all `positive` values from the difference, When I use `ABS` it wont work as `Varchar` is the type. I need `empty string` for `Null Values`.

Comment: I remove [SQLite] tag from your question as your query is not related to it - If you need an equivalent query in SQLite edit your question - Also you need to add a `WHEN` after `CASE` ;).

Answer (score 4):

Why are you converting to `varchar()`?  Actually, this question looks vaguely familiar, and I think I already warned about using `varchar()` without a length in SQL Server.

If you need the value as a string and positive, then do the conversion *after* abs:

```
COALESCE(CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, DATE1, DATE2)) as VARCHAR(255)), '')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting `ABS` before you convert it to `varchar`?

```
CASE 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL(Convert(varchar,ABS(DATEDIFF(day, DATE1, DATE2))),'')
```